# Examples of many timestamp formats?

Tags: validation, timestamp

I'm looking for example data files that contain many different, messy timestamp formats. The weirder the better. I want to see very pathological

[Sumo Logic](https://help.sumologic.com/Send-Data/Sources/04Reference-Information-for-Sources/Timestamps%2C-Time-Zones%2C-Time-Ranges%2C-and-Date-Formats) has a pretty good list, but only single examples:

```
dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss ZZZZ   19/Apr/2010:06:36:15 -0700
dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss        09/Mar/2004 22:02:40 08691
MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a     Dec 2, 2010 2:39:58 AM
MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss        Jun 09 2011 15:28:14
MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy        Apr 20 00:00:35 2010
MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy   Feb 07 15:22:31 -0700 2016
MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ        Sep 28 19:00:00 +0000
MMM dd HH:mm:ss             Mar 16 08:12:04
```

Ideally, I'd love to have multiple examples for every format.

Comment: PS: Apologies if this isn't the right place on SO for this kind of request. I'm not sure where else to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Separators can be hyphen,underscore,space,comma
If you are looking for weird time stamp formats there are plenty that use the above mentioned separators.

Example yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss  = 2017_10_20_00_06_00